# How to use an API service that sends a cookie auth from a POST request to then you use it with GET requests?

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch-api, same-origin-policy

I was playing a bit with fetch then I got stuck into an issue.

There is an API service here in Brazil that responses public bus services traffic. To get the resources you first need to send a POST request that gives you a cookie auth and after that you can make the GET requests.

In this stage I can get the POST auth cookie but when trying to GET data later it returns an 401 error and same site. I guess it is because I am not being able to send the cookie into the GET request, am I right?
Here is the error from console:

> XHRGEThttp://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v2.1/Posicao/Linha?codigoLinha=856
> [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 13ms]
> Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute 2
> Cookie “apiCredentials” has been rejected because it is in a cross-site context and its “SameSite” is “Lax” or “Strict”. Autenticar
> Cookie “apiCredentials” has been rejected because it is in a cross-site context and its “SameSite” is “Lax” or “Strict”. Autenticar
>  bust.html:32:28

In Python I can do it easily with the session command but I am not being able to do with fetch in JavaScript.

Does anyone knows how to manage that code to work and get the response from the API service.

// this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>

const api_url = 'http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v2.1/Posicao/Linha?codigoLinha=856'

const auth_url = 'http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v2.1/Login/Autenticar?token=1ce7717aac41a2c9315fb17054b93713459dae903e6914999dcea325dc7baa61'

fetch(auth_url, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            credentials: 'include',
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.headers.get('set-cookie')); // undefined
                console.log(document.cookie); // nope
        });



fetch(api_url, {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            credentials: 'include',
        })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));


  </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `no-cors` doesn't let you use _anything_ from the response by design. I wrote something about `no-cors` but it's often misunderstood: https://evertpot.com/no-cors/

Comment: Thank you very much Evert. Your article is excelent and pointed for one direction a should not go! :-). I will try without cors/no-cors and keep studying.